# What is causing my UMTS modem to hang up?

Tags: networking, networkmanager, syslog

I am trying to established PPP communication to my mobile ISP with `wvdial`, but I always get **modem hang up** message. In my `syslog` I can see some activity:

```
Oct 29 07:48:47 linuxbox kernel: [31222.852253] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
Oct 29 07:48:47 linuxbox pppd[24590]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Oct 29 07:48:47 linuxbox pppd[24590]: Using interface ppp0
Oct 29 07:48:47 linuxbox pppd[24590]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB2
Oct 29 07:48:47 linuxbox pppd[24590]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Oct 29 07:48:47 linuxbox pppd[24590]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Oct 29 07:48:47 linuxbox kernel: [31223.014123] PPP BSD Compression module registered
Oct 29 07:48:47 linuxbox kernel: [31223.061839] PPP Deflate Compression module registered
Oct 29 07:48:47 linuxbox ifplugd(ppp0)[24612]: ifplugd 0.28 initializing.
Oct 29 07:48:47 linuxbox ifplugd(ppp0)[24612]: Using interface ppp0/00:00:00:00:00:00
Oct 29 07:48:47 linuxbox ifplugd(ppp0)[24612]: Using detection mode: IFF_RUNNING
Oct 29 07:48:47 linuxbox ifplugd(ppp0)[24612]: Initialization complete, link beat detected.
Oct 29 07:48:47 linuxbox ifplugd(ppp0)[24612]: Executing '/etc/ifplugd/ifplugd.action ppp0 up'.
Oct 29 07:48:47 linuxbox ifplugd(ppp0)[24612]: client: Ignoring unknown interface ppp0=ppp0.
Oct 29 07:48:47 linuxbox ifplugd(ppp0)[24612]: Program executed successfully.
Oct 29 07:49:08 linuxbox pppd[24590]: Modem hangup
Oct 29 07:49:08 linuxbox pppd[24590]: Connection terminated.
Oct 29 07:49:08 linuxbox avahi-daemon[1946]: Withdrawing workstation service for ppp0.
Oct 29 07:49:08 linuxbox pppd[24590]: Exit.
Oct 29 07:49:08 linuxbox ifplugd(ppp0)[24612]: Link beat lost.
Oct 29 07:49:08 linuxbox ifplugd(ppp0)[24612]: Exiting.
Oct 29 07:49:13 linuxbox pppd[24697]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Oct 29 07:49:13 linuxbox pppd[24697]: Using interface ppp0
Oct 29 07:49:13 linuxbox pppd[24697]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB2
Oct 29 07:49:14 linuxbox pppd[24697]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Oct 29 07:49:14 linuxbox pppd[24697]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Oct 29 07:49:14 linuxbox ifplugd(ppp0)[24711]: ifplugd 0.28 initializing.
Oct 29 07:49:14 linuxbox ifplugd(ppp0)[24711]: Using interface ppp0/00:00:00:00:00:00
Oct 29 07:49:14 linuxbox ifplugd(ppp0)[24711]: Using detection mode: IFF_RUNNING
Oct 29 07:49:14 linuxbox ifplugd(ppp0)[24711]: Initialization complete, link beat detected.
Oct 29 07:49:14 linuxbox ifplugd(ppp0)[24711]: Executing '/etc/ifplugd/ifplugd.action ppp0 up'.
Oct 29 07:49:14 linuxbox ifplugd(ppp0)[24711]: client: Ignoring unknown interface ppp0=ppp0.
Oct 29 07:49:14 linuxbox ifplugd(ppp0)[24711]: Program executed successfully.
Oct 29 07:49:35 linuxbox pppd[24697]: Modem hangup
Oct 29 07:49:35 linuxbox pppd[24697]: Connection terminated.
Oct 29 07:49:35 linuxbox avahi-daemon[1946]: Withdrawing workstation service for ppp0.
Oct 29 07:49:35 linuxbox pppd[24697]: Exit.
Oct 29 07:49:35 linuxbox ifplugd(ppp0)[24711]: Link beat lost.
Oct 29 07:49:36 linuxbox ifplugd(ppp0)[24711]: Exiting.
```

What is causing this problem?

Comment: "Ignoring unknown interface ppp0=ppp0" seems fairly indicative.

Comment: I tried with "pure" AT command set via minicom. I established GPRS connection to the mobile network and get PDP context:

`AT+CGDCONT?`
`+CGDCONT: 1,"IP",<my_ISP's_name>,"0.0.0.0",0,0`

When I try to active the session:

`AT+CGACT=1,1`

 the modem stops responding.

Comment: When i had a similar problem with wvdial, I switched to NetworkManager and these hang ups went away. See my [related question and answer here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198554/3g-connection-with-wvdial-gets-no-ip-exits-with-code-16)