# 3G connection with wvdial gets no IP, exits with code 16

Tags: networkmanager, raspbian, ppp, 3g, wvdial

I am trying to establish a 3G connection with Raspbian, a 3G USB dongle, `usb_modeswitch` and `wvdial`. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-setup-usb-3g-modem-raspberry-pi-using-usbmodeswitch-and-wvdial) which has worked well before with a different 3G dongle.

My 3G dongle is a ZTE D6601, the SIM has no PIN and the connection works flawlessly with the ISPs tool under Windows and under Ubuntu 15 with the built-in mobile broadband tool. But I need to do this on a Raspberry Pi and from the command line.

This is what I have tried so far: When I boot Raspbian, `lsusb` returns

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 19d2:0154 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
```

I then run

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -I -v 19d2 -p 0154 -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf
```

Which changes the ProductID to

```
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 19d2:0108 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
```

There is more than one 3G dongle with 0154 as `DefaultProduct` ID so the standard switching rules of `usb_modeswitch` don't work. 0108 is what Ubuntu switches the device to or what happens when I `sudo eject` the virtual CD drive, so I used that.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` was only changed to use a WiFi connection:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

So far, so good. When I run `sudo wvdialconf`, a modem is detected at `/dev/ttyUSB1`. I then run `sudo wvdial dcom` with `dcom` being defined like this (APN "e-connect" is correct, no user / pass required):

```
[Dialer dcom]
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB1
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","e-connect"
Stupid Mode = 1
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Phone = *99#
ISDN = 0
Username = { }
Auto Reconnect = 1
Password = { }
Baud = 460800
```

The shell returns this:

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","e-connect"
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","e-connect"
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*99#
CONNECT 21600000
--> Carrier detected.  Starting PPP immediately.
--> Starting pppd at Sat Apr 25 18:09:08 2015
--> Pid of pppd: 5530
--> Using interface ppp0
--> pppd: [08]FX[01]�FX[01]8GX[01]p<X[01]�PX[01]�QX[01] (+4 more times)
```

After running this, `ifconfig` shows that `ppp0` was created but no IP address is assigned. Then, about 10 seconds later this happens:

```
--> Disconnecting at Sat Apr 25 18:09:39 2015
--> The PPP daemon has died: A modem hung up the phone (exit code = 16)
--> man pppd explains pppd error codes in more detail.
--> Try again and look into /var/log/messages and the wvdial and pppd man pages for more information.
--> Auto Reconnect will be attempted in 5 seconds
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","e-connect"
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","e-connect"
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","e-connect"
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","e-connect"
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*99#
ERROR
--> Invalid dial command.
--> Disconnecting at Sat Apr 25 18:09:45 2015
```

If I run `wvdial dcom` again, it will repeat the output of the second connection attempt above (`Invalid dial command`) and not even configure `ppp0`. Weirdly, after a quick `sudo wvdialconf` (during which `/etv/wvdial.conf` remains unchanged), I can connect again, but it will again assign no IP and break after 10 seconds. I have replicated this several times.

Maybe this is also interesting: `wlan0` loses its IP the moment `ppp0` is created and I can only get it back running `sudo ifdown wlan0` and `sudo ifup wlan0` even though it is set to automatically reconnect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a way: I dropped `wvdial` and used `nmcli` (from the `network-manager` package) instead. I established the connection 10 hours ago and it is still active with the same IP. Here's how I did it:

**Step 1:** Get `usb-modeswitch` to run so your 3G USB stick is recognized as a modem, not a storage device. I am not going to cover the details here as there are many tutorials out there ([example](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-setup-usb-3g-modem-raspberry-pi-using-usbmodeswitch-and-wvdial)).

**Step 2:** Install [NetworkManager](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager) on the RPi: `sudo apt-get install network-manager network-manager-gnome -y`. Check whether NetworkManager recognizes your modem by running `nmcli dev`. If yes, you should see a table like this:

```
DEVICE        TYPE                      STATE
ttyUSB2        gsm                      disconnected
```

(If no, your `usb-modeswitch` may have failed and your system cannot find a modem.)

**Step 3:** Start the X server: `startx`, open the NetworkManager from the menu and create a new "Mobile Broadband" connection ("Mobile Broadband" tab > "Add"). The wizard will guide you through the process even letting you select your provider so you don't have to bother with APN settings. The tool will create a connection file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` and you should take note of the name of that file as it will be used as the connection name in the next step.

**Step 4:** As I said in my question, I need to be able to run this from the command line without the X server and the way to do that is by running `sudo nmcli con up id "Connection ID"`, the connection ID being the name of the connection you created in step 2. That should be all. To disconnect, execute `sudo nmcli con down id "Connection ID"`.